# limit of detection (interval censored) CI

Tags: confidence-interval, interval-censoring

I'm trying to compare data I have to other data for which I have mean and std (normally distributed). My data consists of several varibales, some of which are interval censored due to machine limit of detection.
I can deduce the quantiles but is there any other statistic I can deduce which will assist on comparing the parameter rather than the sample statistics?

Comment: This is rather sparse. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals here? Can you provide some example data?

Comment: There are regression models for interval censored data, but it's unclear exactly what you are looking for: *what* is the parameter of interest that you are referring too?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to compare the data collected to a known mean and std to establish whether the data is derived from a similiar population as well as provide either mean and std for the new data or confidence interval to allow that comparison.
I am not sure how the previous mean and std were calculated to avoid this problem but for the time being I need to assume the statistics provided for comparison are as given to me.